# Struct Fields Not Updating When Another Object Tells Struct to Update

Tags: go, struct

I have the following `struct` that has a function that can update its fields:

```
type Dog struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func (dog *Dog) growOld() {    
    dog.name = "old dog"
    dog.age++
}
```

The above works fine on its own. However, when the `struct` belongs to another object and said object tells the `struct` to update its fields, the changes seem to occur but do not get applied:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Owner struct {
    dog Dog
}

func newOwner(dog Dog) Owner {
    var owner Owner
    owner.dog = dog

    return owner
}

func (owner Owner) tellDogToGrowOld() {
    owner.dog.growOld()
}

func main() {
    var dog Dog
    dog.name = "dog"

    owner := newOwner(dog)
    owner.tellDogToGrowOld()       

    fmt.Println(dog) // dog's name is still `dog` and age is 0.
}
```

I assume I have to use `pointers` somehow but can't quite figure out how.

Comment: `tellDogToGrowOld` needs to be defined on a pointer just like you did with `growOld`. Or, alternatively, `Owner`'s dog field needs to be pointer to `Dog`.

Comment: @mkopriva Hey, it worked! Please add this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @mkopriva I went with the `Owner`'s dog field should be a pointer to `Dog` approach because it's the closest to "pass-by-reference" in other languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of a method's receiver should be a pointer type if you want that method to modify the receiver's state.

That is, the same way as you've declared the `growOld` method, the `tellDogToGrowOld` method should also have a pointer reciever:

```
func (owner *Owner) tellDogToGrowOld() {
    owner.dog.growOld()
}
```

Alternatively, you could make the field that you want to modify to be a pointer, e.g.:

```
type Owner struct {
    dog *Dog
}

func newOwner(dog *Dog) Owner {
    var owner Owner
    owner.dog = dog

    return owner
}

func (owner Owner) tellDogToGrowOld() {
    owner.dog.growOld()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the field in the Owner to be a *Dog not a Dog

```
type Owner struct {
    dog *Dog
}

func newOwner(dog *Dog) Owner {
    var owner Owner
    owner.dog = dog

    return owner
}
```

when calling from main use &dog

```
var dog Dog
    dog.name = "dog"

    owner := newOwner(&dog)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LpFqW09dOs4